# Circle with large radius is drawn incorrectly in Firefox

Tags: firefox, canvas, geometry

Circles with very large radii are not displayed correctly in Firefox 100.0.2. on Ubuntu Linux.

Here is a minimal example that works correctly in Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge, but not in Firefox. The circle must contain the point, but for some reasons it does not.

```js
const container = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
container.append(canvas);
canvas.style.border = "1px solid black";
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";


ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(195, 66.36363636363637, 2, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(286.57941279334176, 375.00999441910346, 2, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
          
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(-74484.10354947454, 22392.54035201409, 77945.02340554907, 0, 2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Circle</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mycanvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the arc angle is reduced, it gets better. For example, ctx.arc(-74484.10354947454, 22392.54035201409, 77945.02340554907, 7*Math.PI/4, 2*Math.PI); works perfectly.

Comment: in GDI ellipse/arc docs there is note: `Windows 95/98/Me: The sum of the coordinates of the bounding rectangle cannot exceed 32,767. The sum of nLeftRect and nRightRect or nTopRect and nBottomRect parameters cannot exceed 32,767.` not sure what Firefox uses behind the scenes for rendering but might be related...